# How to detect recurrent patterns in a textfile

Tags: parsing, text-files

To simplify a function with many terms, a program would be useful that searches for patterns in a file and arranges them in a ranking list. I can imagine that this is an elaborate process, but I'm sure there are people who have built something like this. 
An example of a text:

```
sin(t1)*cos(t1)*t1+t1-sin(t1)*sin(t1-pi)
```

This should give me such an output like this (min. 2 letters):

```
 6x: "t1" 
 4x: "(t1"
 3x: "n(t1"
 3x: "sin"
 3x: "sin("
 2x: "sin(t1)"

 etc.
```

Does this problem have a name (which I don't know)? Is there a known algorithm that could solve the problem for me?

Comment: I think this is not a design pattern, the designer patter resolve a recurrent problem, this problem can be resolved with the regex, an example [here](https://regexr.com/)

Comment: That's right! I chose the wrong day. Hope "pattern-maching" fits better.

Comment: I thinnk parsing is the correct tag

Comment: I have written a program which now tries out all options with the parameters: Maximum and minimum string length, and minimum occurrence.  It's very inefficient, but I think it helps me for now. I guess there are better algorithms than trying everything. I'll share my program here in the forum when I've tested it a bit.

Comment: When you post the your program, sent me message so I will see it

Comment: Posted. Didn't figure out how to send you a message.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a small program with QT, which fulfills the task. The approach is to try everything. To solve my problem, it will probably take a few days, because the text files are very large.
If I have the following text as input ("text.txt"):

```
sin(t1)*cos(t1)*t1+t1-sin(t1)*sin(t1-pi)
```

I have with the parameters: length 2-5, minimum occurrence: 3

following result:

```
t1 6
(t 4
(t1 4
si 3
in 3
n( 3
1) 3
)* 3
sin 3
in( 3
n(t 3
t1) 3
1)* 3
sin( 3
in(t 3
n(t1 3
(t1) 3
t1)* 3
sin(t 3
in(t1 3
(t1)* 3
```

Code:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <qdebug.h>
#include <qstring.h>
#include <qfile.h>
#include <qtextstream.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QString * wholefile = new QString;
    uint64_t minchar = 2;
    uint64_t maxchar = 5;
    uint64_t min_occur = 3;

    QFile file("text.txt");
    if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        qDebug()<<"error reading file";
    }
    QTextStream in(&file);
    while(!in.atEnd()) {
        QString line = in.readLine();
        wholefile->append(line);
    }

    file.close();
    QStringList * allpatterns = new QStringList;
    for(uint64_t i=minchar; i<=maxchar;i++){
        for(uint64_t pos=0; pos<wholefile->length()-i;pos++){
            QString pattern = wholefile->mid(pos,i);
            if(allpatterns->contains(pattern)==0){
                allpatterns->append(pattern);
            }
        }
    }

    uint64_t * strcnt = new uint64_t[allpatterns->length()];
    uint64_t maximum_cnt = 0;
    QStringList * interestingpatterns = new QStringList;
    uint64_t nr_of_patterns = 0;
    for(uint64_t i=0; i<allpatterns->length();i++){
        QString str = allpatterns->at(i);
        strcnt[nr_of_patterns] = wholefile->count(str);
        if(strcnt[nr_of_patterns]>=min_occur){
            if(strcnt[nr_of_patterns]>maximum_cnt){
                maximum_cnt = strcnt[nr_of_patterns];
            }
            interestingpatterns->append(str);
            nr_of_patterns++;
        }
    }
    /* display result*/
    QFile file2("out.txt");
    if (!file2.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text))
        qDebug()<<"error writing file";
    QTextStream out(&file2);

    uint64_t current_max = maximum_cnt;
    while(current_max>=min_occur){
        for(uint64_t i=0; i<interestingpatterns->length();i++){
            if(strcnt[i]==current_max){
                QString str = interestingpatterns->at(i);
                qDebug()<<str<<strcnt[i];
                out <<str<<" "<< QString::number(strcnt[i])<<"\n";
            }
        }
        current_max--;
    }
    file2.close();

    return a.exec();
}
```